# In Angular 2, How do I send Checkbox Values to my function in the component?

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular and using NgFor, I am displaying elements which I want to select them, upon clicking I should get the ID in the Component function.
But I tried using ngModel and all the buttons get selected.

I am trying to get the (hero.id) when the user checks the boxes. How do I do it? What are my mistakes.

> My HTML

```html
<div>
  <form (submit)="onSubmit()">
    <tr *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
      <input type="checkbox" name="timeid" value={ {hero.id}} class={{hero.id}}>{{hero.time}}<br>
    </tr>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Remove Alarms">
  </form>
</div>
```

> Here is my component.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ValidateService} from '../../services/validate.service';
import {AlarmService} from '../../services/alarm.service';
import {FlashMessagesService} from 'angular2-flash-messages';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {

  hours;
  id: String;
  timeid: String;
  time;
  heroes: any[];


  constructor(
    private validateService: ValidateService,
    private FlashMessage: FlashMessagesService,
    private Router: Router,
    private AlarmService: AlarmService
  ) {


  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.ui();
  }

  onRegisterSubmit() {

    this.ui();

    this.heroes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users'));

    var timeStr = new Date(this.hours);
    var date = new Date(timeStr);
    var day = date.getUTCDate();
    var year = date.getUTCFullYear();
    var month = date.getUTCMonth() + 1;
    var hour = date.getUTCHours();
    var minutes = date.getUTCMinutes();
    var dateStr = "Time is " + hour + ":" + minutes + " in 24 HRS Time and the Date is " + day + "/" + month + "/" + year;

    console.log(dateStr);

    var user = {
      hours: (new Date(this.hours.replace('T', ' ').replace('-', '/'))).valueOf(),
      id: new Date().getTime(),
      time: dateStr,
      flag: 0,
    }


    setTimeout(() => {
      this.FlashMessage.show('Your alarm has been added.', {
        cssClass: 'alert-success',
        timeout: 5000
      });
    }, 10);

    var storage = localStorage.getItem('users');
    var final = [];
    if (storage == null || typeof(storage) == undefined) {
      final.push(user);

      localStorage.setItem('users', JSON.stringify(final));
      let time = new Date().getTime()

      this.AlarmService.setUpAlarms(time);

    } else {
      var get = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users'));
      var size = Object.keys(get).length;

      for (var i = 0; i < get.length; i++) {
        final.push(get[i]);
      }
      final.push(user);
      localStorage.setItem('users', JSON.stringify(final));
      let time = new Date().getTime()

      this.AlarmService.setUpAlarms(time);
    }

  }


  ui() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.heroes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users'));
      console.log(this.heroes);
    }, 100);
  }

  onSubmit() {
    var user = {
      timeid: this.timeid,
    }
    console.log(user);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

here is a simple example:

> plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/1nWBj5Z48vFYPOw6nbDa?p=preview

to detect the user checked the box, you need to use the `change` event binding. then call your function and pass it that change `$event`. the `$event` here is crucial syntax. then you can access all kinds of things from that event, mainly the `target` which is the HTML element `<input>` that was changed.. then you'd get the id as it is the value of that input.

```
    //our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <div>
        <form>
          <tr *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
          <input (change)="check($event)" type="checkbox" name="timeid" value ="{{hero.id}}" class="{{hero.id}}">{{hero.time}}<br>
          </tr>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  // sample heros with an id and time..
  heroes =
    [
      {"id":1,"time":"2017-06-01T05:00:00.000Z"},
      {"id":2,"time":"2017-06-02T05:00:00.000Z"},
      {"id":3,"time":"2017-06-03T05:00:00.000Z"},
      {"id":4,"time":"2017-06-04T05:00:00.000Z"},
      {"id":5,"time":"2017-06-05T05:00:00.000Z"}
    ];
  constructor() {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.heroes))
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }
  check(e){
    console.log(e)
    console.log(e.target.checked)
    console.log(e.target.value)
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: It works but can you please explain me what does heroes do here? It works but I will be more knowledgeable if I understand. So do they communicate? What is newDate for?

Comment: oh, it is just a simple array.. let me update the answer with an explicit array instead :)

Comment: Thankyou so much sir, a million upvotes you. You saved my day!

Comment: Thats why I always include the code in the answer :) should be easy to move it to a plunker or otherwise :)